# Why GitHub C++ Core Guideline says that global object better than singleton?

Tags: c++, singleton, cpp-core-guidelines, global-object

[The Github C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#-r6-avoid-non-const-global-variables) say:

> A global object is often better than a singleton.

I always thought the opposite. Something has changed since then in the C++?
Or may be it's just another typo?

Comment: Random guidelines from the internet aren't worth any more than the explanation/justification they include.  In this case it's none, so it's worthless.  You're just as likely to find some other guideline that says the opposite.  If you want reasoned arguments on a specific question such as "when to prefer singleton over global object or vice versa", best to ask it directly.

Comment: Look again. It says that *as an exception* to a rule *against* globals, entitled "Avoid non-const global variables". Don't take things out of context.

Comment: @TonyD It's not random, because proposed by Stroustrup.

Comment: @TonyD, but... but... the authors...

Comment: @alexolut So ask Stroustrup. What's the point of asking here? Is Bjarne a member?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the rationale for avoiding singletons from the same [guideline collection](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Ri-singleton):

> I.3: Avoid singletons
>
> Reason
>
> Singletons are basically complicated global objects in disguise.
>
> Example

```
class Singleton {
    // ... lots of stuff to ensure that only one Singleton object is created,
    // that it is initialized properly, etc.
};
```

> There are many variants of the singleton idea. That's part of the problem.

My analysis of the intentions of the author:

Simpler is better. If disguising global objects in singletons doesn't solve the problems of global objects - like the guideline above implies - then there is no use in complicating the code by the use of the disguise.

Comment: Both singleton and global object are bad. But why authors recommend using of global object instead of singleton? That's the question.

Comment: @alexolut it's just a matter of preference, global variables aren't that bad & can be useful in quite some places. it's just that they are diffcult to handle

Comment: @alexolut the quoted guideline states that singletons are global objects in disguise. I would infer that means they don't solve the problems of global objects. It also states that singletons are more complicated than global objects. Simpler is better.

Comment: And if you read the Exception to the I.3 guideline in this answer, it's *"You can use the simplest "singleton" (so simple that it is often not considered a singleton) to get initialization on first use"*, so the authors are hardly arguing against singletons *in earnest*.

Comment: How do the guidelines address using singleton where there should only be one instance of an object (like a physical resource)?